# Adding a single label to the legend for a series of different data points plotted inside a designated bin in Python using matplotlib.pyplot.plot()

Tags: python, csv, numpy, dictionary

I have a script for plotting astronomical data of redmapping clusters using a csv file. I could get the data points in it and want to plot them using different colors depending on their redshift values: I am binning the dataset into 3 bins (0.1-0.2, 0.2-0.25, 0.25,0.31) based on the redshift.

The problem arises with my code after I distinguish to what bin the datapoint belongs: I want to have 3 labels in the legend corresponding to red, green and blue data points, but this is not happening and I don't know why. I am using `plot()` instead of `scatter()` as I also had to do the best fit from the data in the same figure. So everything needs to be in 1 figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as py
import csv

z = open("Sheet4CSV.csv","rU")
data = csv.reader(z)
x = []
y = []
ylow = []
yupp = []
xlow = []
xupp = []
redshift = []

for r in data:
    x.append(float(r[2]))
    y.append(float(r[5]))
    xlow.append(float(r[3]))
    xupp.append(float(r[4]))
    ylow.append(float(r[6]))
    yupp.append(float(r[7]))
    redshift.append(float(r[1]))

from operator import sub
xerr_l = map(sub,x,xlow)
xerr_u = map(sub,xupp,x)
yerr_l = map(sub,y,ylow)
yerr_u = map(sub,yupp,y)

py.xlabel("$Original\ Tx\ XCS\ pipeline\ Tx\ keV$")
py.ylabel("$Iterative\ Tx\ pipeline\ keV$")
py.xlim(0,12)
py.ylim(0,12)
py.title("Redmapper Clusters comparison of Tx pipelines")

ax1 = py.subplot(111)

##Problem starts here after the previous line##

for p in redshift:
    for i in xrange(84):
        p=redshift[i]

        if 0.1<=p<0.2:

            ax1.plot(x[i],y[i],color="b", marker='.', linestyle = " ")#, label = "$z < 0.2$")
            exit


        if 0.2<=p<0.25:
            ax1.plot(x[i],y[i],color="g", marker='.', linestyle = " ")#, label="$0.2 \leq z < 0.25$")
            exit

        if 0.25<=p<=0.3:
            ax1.plot(x[i],y[i],color="r", marker='.', linestyle = " ")#, label="$z \geq 0.25$")
            exit

##There seems nothing wrong after this point##

py.errorbar(x,y,yerr=[yerr_l,yerr_u],xerr=[xerr_l,xerr_u], fmt= " ",ecolor='magenta', label="Error bars")

cof = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
p = np.poly1d(cof)
l = np.linspace(0,12,100)
py.plot(l,p(l),"black",label="Best fit")
py.plot([0,15],[0,15],"black", linestyle="dotted", linewidth=2.0, label="line $y=x$")
py.grid()

box = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position([box.x1,box.y1,box.width, box.height])
py.legend(loc='center left',bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5))
py.show()
```

In the 1st 'for' loop, I have indexed every value 'p' in the list 'redshift' so that bins can be created using 'if' statement. But if I add the labels that are hashed out against each py.plot() inside the 'if' statements, each data point 'i' that gets plotted in the figure as an intersection of (x[i],y[i]) takes the label and my entire legend attains in total 87 labels (including the 3 mentioned in the code at other places)!!!!!!

**I essentially need 1 label for each bin...**

Please tell me what needs to done after the bins are created and py.plot() commands used...Thanks in advance :-)
Sorry I cannot post my image here due to low reputation!

The data 'appended' for x, y and redshift lists from the csv file are as follows:

```
x=[5.031,10.599,10.589,8.548,9.089,8.675,3.588,1.244,3.023,8.632,8.953,7.603,7.513,2.917,7.344,7.106,3.889,7.287,3.367,6.839,2.801,2.316,1.328,6.31,6.19,6.329,6.025,5.629,6.123,5.892,5.438,4.398,4.542,4.624,4.501,4.504,5.033,5.068,4.197,2.854,4.784,2.158,4.054,3.124,3.961,4.42,3.853,3.658,1.858,4.537,2.072,3.573,3.041,5.837,3.652,3.209,2.742,2.732,1.312,3.635,2.69,3.32,2.488,2.996,2.269,1.701,3.935,2.015,0.798,2.212,1.672,1.925,3.21,1.979,1.794,2.624,2.027,3.66,1.073,1.007,1.57,0.854,0.619,0.547]
y=[5.255,10.897,11.045,9.125,9.387,17.719,4.025,1.389,4.152,8.703,9.051,8.02,7.774,3.139,7.543,7.224,4.155,7.416,3.905,6.868,2.909,2.658,1.651,6.454,6.252,6.541,6.152,5.647,6.285,6.079,5.489,4.541,4.634,8.851,4.554,4.555,5.559,5.144,5.311,5.839,5.364,3.18,4.352,3.379,4.059,4.575,3.914,5.736,2.304,4.68,3.187,3.756,3.419,9.118,4.595,3.346,3.603,6.313,1.816,4.34,2.732,4.978,2.719,3.761,2.623,2.1,4.956,2.316,4.231,2.831,1.954,2.248,6.573,2.276,2.627,3.85,3.545,25.405,3.996,1.347,1.679,1.435,0.759,0.677]
redshift = [0.12,0.25,0.23,0.23,0.27,0.26,0.12,0.27,0.17,0.18,0.17,0.3,0.23,0.1,0.23,0.29,0.29,0.12,0.13,0.26,0.11,0.24,0.13,0.21,0.17,0.2,0.3,0.29,0.23,0.27,0.25,0.21,0.11,0.15,0.1,0.26,0.23,0.12,0.23,0.26,0.2,0.17,0.22,0.26,0.25,0.12,0.19,0.24,0.18,0.15,0.27,0.14,0.14,0.29,0.29,0.26,0.15,0.29,0.24,0.24,0.23,0.26,0.29,0.22,0.13,0.18,0.24,0.14,0.24,0.24,0.17,0.26,0.29,0.11,0.14,0.26,0.28,0.26,0.28,0.27,0.23,0.26,0.23,0.19]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add to your post the first 2 lines of your csv-file? I also take it you have never worked with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) before?

Comment: I have worked with numpy but the 'if' statements under the 2nd 'for' loop is creating the problem here. It is only that part that I need help with. I just mentioned the entire code here so that the scene becomes clear as to what I aim to do. Ok, I shall edit the post immediately to add the data for x,y and redshift lists as these are the only relevent ones I suppose for my question.

Comment: Please add to your post the first 2 lines of your csv-file, that will allow us to help much more efficiently.

Comment: Can you simply try with what I just provided for x, y and redshift? Those are the ones related to my problem here. The bins need to be created from redshift and colors set for each bin to plot x vs y (not scatter, essentially!) as you can see line of best fit is also needed in the same figure. Scatter ruins the image here!

Comment: You can see in the redshift data there is no value greater than 0.3, so the last 'if' statement includes its upper limit. Moreover, the value 84 in xrange(84) is the length of all the lists!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with numerical data like this, you should really consider using a numerical library, like numpy.

The problem in your code arises from processing each record (a coordinate (x,y) and the corresponding value `redshift`) one at a time. You are calling `plot` for each point, thereby creating legends for each of those 84 datapoints. You should consider your "bins" as groups of data that belong to the same dataset and process them as such. You could use "[logical masks](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-d55e594d46b4f347c20efe1b4c65c92779f06268)" to distinguish between your "bins", as shown below.

It's also not clear why you call `exit` after each plotting action.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([5.031,10.599,10.589,8.548,9.089,8.675,3.588,1.244,3.023,8.632,8.953,7.603,7.513,2.917,7.344,7.106,3.889,7.287,3.367,6.839,2.801,2.316,1.328,6.31,6.19,6.329,6.025,5.629,6.123,5.892,5.438,4.398,4.542,4.624,4.501,4.504,5.033,5.068,4.197,2.854,4.784,2.158,4.054,3.124,3.961,4.42,3.853,3.658,1.858,4.537,2.072,3.573,3.041,5.837,3.652,3.209,2.742,2.732,1.312,3.635,2.69,3.32,2.488,2.996,2.269,1.701,3.935,2.015,0.798,2.212,1.672,1.925,3.21,1.979,1.794,2.624,2.027,3.66,1.073,1.007,1.57,0.854,0.619,0.547])
y = np.array([5.255,10.897,11.045,9.125,9.387,17.719,4.025,1.389,4.152,8.703,9.051,8.02,7.774,3.139,7.543,7.224,4.155,7.416,3.905,6.868,2.909,2.658,1.651,6.454,6.252,6.541,6.152,5.647,6.285,6.079,5.489,4.541,4.634,8.851,4.554,4.555,5.559,5.144,5.311,5.839,5.364,3.18,4.352,3.379,4.059,4.575,3.914,5.736,2.304,4.68,3.187,3.756,3.419,9.118,4.595,3.346,3.603,6.313,1.816,4.34,2.732,4.978,2.719,3.761,2.623,2.1,4.956,2.316,4.231,2.831,1.954,2.248,6.573,2.276,2.627,3.85,3.545,25.405,3.996,1.347,1.679,1.435,0.759,0.677])
redshift = np.array([0.12,0.25,0.23,0.23,0.27,0.26,0.12,0.27,0.17,0.18,0.17,0.3,0.23,0.1,0.23,0.29,0.29,0.12,0.13,0.26,0.11,0.24,0.13,0.21,0.17,0.2,0.3,0.29,0.23,0.27,0.25,0.21,0.11,0.15,0.1,0.26,0.23,0.12,0.23,0.26,0.2,0.17,0.22,0.26,0.25,0.12,0.19,0.24,0.18,0.15,0.27,0.14,0.14,0.29,0.29,0.26,0.15,0.29,0.24,0.24,0.23,0.26,0.29,0.22,0.13,0.18,0.24,0.14,0.24,0.24,0.17,0.26,0.29,0.11,0.14,0.26,0.28,0.26,0.28,0.27,0.23,0.26,0.23,0.19])
bin3 = 0.25 <= redshift
bin2 = np.logical_and(0.2 <= redshift, redshift < 0.25)
bin1 = np.logical_and(0.1 <= redshift, redshift < 0.2)

plt.ion()
labels = ("$z < 0.2$", "$0.2 \leq z < 0.25$", "$z \geq 0.25$")
colors = ('r', 'g', 'b')
for bin, label, co in zip( (bin1, bin2, bin3), labels, colors):
    plt.plot(x[bin], y[bin], color=co, ls='none', marker='o', label=label)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I used 'exit' after each 'if' statement (the last 'exit' can be avoided) because after the 1st 'if' statement, in absence of an 'exit', the colors of the points in the other 2 bins (in my code) won't change for the plots in the next 'if' statements but remain the same as the color set for the plot in the 1st 'if' statement. You can see that if you remove 'exit' from each of them and check the color of the data points. They will be the same as that put in the plot command of the 1st 'if' statement.

Comment: I am using numpy to a limited extent. So, I am quite not sure what you did here with bin1, bin2, and bin3. Plus, kindly explain the role that 'ion' and 'zip' play here.

Comment: Ah, `exit` was actually the [`continue` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)! @KishalayChoudhury definitely read the link of logical masks. To summarize: `bin3 = 0.25 <= redshift` will check *in one go* whether the values in `redshift` is larger than .25. `bin3` will then be an array of True and False values (a "boolean array"), having a True on every position where the corresponding redshift value was larger than .25. This basically "tags" each value in redshift.

Comment: The reason why I am requesting you to clarify the roles of the commands used in my last comment is that the Python help() thing did not go so well!! Sorry for the annoyance...

Comment: `help()` will unfortunately not teach you all the tricks of the trade. A lot more is on the internet and that link in my post is a very good place to start learning more about what you can do with `numpy`. Just to clarify, was that graph what you had in mind?

Comment: Ok, so what this means is **bin3** will plot blue-colored data points each time it is True in all 84 cases and nothing at all when False? (The like goes for the other bins as well, got it!)

Comment: Yes, that is the legend that I wanted! But please tell me what 'ion' and 'zip' do, if you don't mind?

Comment: @KishalayChoudhury yes indeed. To be more specific: `x[bin3]` will make a new array that only takes those values in the full `x` where `bin3` is `True`. So `x=[9, 8, 6]; bin=[True, False, True];` then `x[bin] == [9, 6]`.

Comment: Just to add, I could verify from my code that everything I did in that code was correct and all the code lines gave me the exact result that I wanted (just the fact that it took a long time to run because of these 'if' statements!). So, is there a possibility that after these 'if' statements something can be done to include a single label for each set bin?

Comment: @KishalayChoudhury, yes there are ways but they are too lengthy to explain in these comments: better ask a new question if you really want to know. But it is not the typical way of approaching this problem, as you will notice. I take it that this is not the answer you were looking for? Here's what [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) does by the way. `ion` allows interactive plotting, often used with unknown datasets.

Comment: Oh no! I was just curious to know if I could do something better with the code that I have. Otherwise, your answer is very much acceptable :-) Just that, I need to do a bit more research on "logical masks", "zip" and "ion". By the way, does not including 'ion' alter anything in the code?

Comment: @KishalayChoudhury The call to `plt.ion()` can be safely removed here. Also, welcome to Stackoverflow. If you feel this [answer solved your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), you might want to consider accepting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this though.

Comment: Umm...a little snag here! I just replace my entire 2nd 'for loop till the last 'exit' with your code starting 'bin3'....but, it only gave me 1 green circle and 1 blue circle in the figure with all other data points invisible!! Rest all is absolutely fine....! Weird!!

Comment: Your code is, unfortunately, not working because inside _py.errorbar()_ we have **fmt=" "**

Comment: @KishalayChoudhury I'd invite you to chat but you do not yet have sufficient reputation for that. Your last comment is based on a stacktrace error that you're seeing because you do not understand the code yet. Get rid of both your for-loops. The first (outer) loops over every datapoint in `redfields`. The inner loop actually does the same.

Comment: This is an example of plotting using csv data. Hence, the problem is that I need the 1st 'for' loop as I have to bring in data from the csv file to plot the errorbars as well after the data points have been plotted. So, the 1st 'for' loop appends my empty lists that I created to add the csv data to. 'xerr' and 'yerr' in py.errorbar() are based on the lists appended from the csv file using the 1st 'for' loop.

Comment: @KishalayChoudhury my bad, I forgot about the first for-loop. I meant the 2nd and 3rd then. You could get rid of that first loop too (the one that reads in your csv) with e.g. [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) or [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). But you could copy-paste everything starting from `bin3=` in my code after your `Problem starts here after the previous line##`. Try to play around with your data and the code to understand a bit better what it is doing though.

Comment: I don't see where you could find a 3rd 'for' loop in my code! Well, I choose to keep the 1st 'for' loop if that is not a problem for the code later? The problem arises every time because of the `py.errorbar()` command where `fmt=" "` causes all data points (but strangely only 2) to be invisible. The 2 that are visible, however, do not overlap with the bins set as their colors vary from the ones set in the bins in your code. Moreover, if you see my code before the 2nd 'for' loop, if I use those limits on the x and y axes, I get **an impossible point on the graph** that has 4<x<6 but 10<y<12..!!

Comment: Thank you for your time anyways. I will look for the code to work properly.

Comment: @KishalayChoudhury use `fmt=None` if you want there to be no markers, just the errorbars (apparently fmt=" " did something in an mpl version that I'm not using). As for those 2 extra markers you see, sorry I don't have your data and I'm not seeing which code you're running now. I can't help you further.